# Access query not getting correct results

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have an Access database that imports data from Excel.  The database does a comparison between two tables.  I do want to fuss with changing the structure of the data coming from Excel--e.g. there are no primary keys in the Access tables.
When I do a query I do not get the correct results.  I am keeping this as simple as can be.

- **Spec table fields:**
  Dates--*date format,*
  Hours--*number format*
- **Stats table fields:**
  Dates--*date format,*
  Cell--*number format,*
  Texting--*number format*

I have tried all 3 join properties on the Dates field and anytime I repeat the date in the Spec table with the same number of hours my query gives me quadrupling results.

Here is one of my attempts:

```sql
SELECT Spec.Dates, Spec.Hours, Stats.Dates, Stats.Cell, Stats.Texting
FROM Spec RIGHT JOIN Stats ON Spec.Dates = Stats.Dates
GROUP BY Spec.Dates, Spec.Hours, Stats.Dates, Stats.Cell, Stats.Texting;
```

I hope this is clear--I can attach a sample database if needed.

Comment: What is the query?

Comment: A query is a request for data results, for action on data, or for both. You can use a query to answer a simple question, to perform calculations, to combine data from different tables, or even to add, change, or delete table data. Queries that you use to retrieve data from a table or to make calculations are called select queries. Queries that add, change, or delete data are called action queries.

Comment: You need to be able to uniquely identify a match - dates and hous may be duplicated so you need more than that. i.d. Employee ID or Name or Unit or ...

Comment: I didn't ask what is ***a*** query :)  I'm asking what is ***your*** SQL query that is not working.  You didn't post the SQL query in your question.

Comment: SELECT Spec.Dates, Spec.Hours, Stats.Dates, Stats.Cell, Stats.Texting
FROM Spec RIGHT JOIN Stats ON Spec.Dates = Stats.Dates
GROUP BY Spec.Dates, Spec.Hours, Stats.Dates, Stats.Cell, Stats.Texting;

Comment: Hi Wayne--If I add in a unique field such as ID and join on that field I do get the correct results but the data is coming from Excel and I did not want to alter the table structure in Access unless I can add in the field to the two tables automatically when I import them.

Comment: Hi Hans--I all ready misunderstood a comment-LOL-so I don't want to repeat that again.  I do not understand your comment?

Comment: You say 'import from Excel...' and 'database ... two tables'. Are you importing two tables from excel, or one from Excel already have one in Access? Without knowing the content of the excel sheet(s) and/or content of Access tables, we have no idea if there is any existing data to match on. My bet is you have something that has not been explained yet?  If you were to just look at the data, how would YOU match the two tables? Once we know that, we can help.

Comment: Hi.  I still am not sure what Hans Up means?  Sorry to confuse or ask a question that is too hard when you cannot see it visually.  I decided to take Wayne's suggestion and added in a autonumber field using temp tables and append and delete queries.  This gives me the right results.  I am now researching some code that might do this automatically resetting the autonumber each time back to 1.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'resetting the AutoNumber back to 1'. AutoNumber fields get incremented each time a new record is added. One way to set it back to one is to delete all rows in the table, then compact & repair. Or you can look at: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/812718

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Spec.Dates, Spec.Hours, FIRST(Stats.Cell) AS Cell, FIRST(Stats.Texting) AS Texting
FROM Spec RIGHT JOIN Stats ON Spec.Dates = Stats.Dates
GROUP BY Spec.Dates, Spec.Hours
```

This is unlikely what you are looking for but it may point you into the direction of what is going wrong. maybe if you can show us a set of records and results, both the actual and the expected ones I could get closer to a real answer.

```
For example:

Spec table:
5/5/2016 4:00
5/5/2016 5:00

Stats table:
5/5/2016 'Cell A' 'Texting A'
5/5/2016 'Cell B' 'texting B'
```

Would indeed result in 4 separate result lines for your query with all 4 combinations of the above 2x2 records. As far as I can tell there is no data in your database/import to get anything different (for example to only tie the 4:00 time to the Cell A/Texting A stat).

Comment: Hi.  That did not work  How do I attach the sample database?

Comment: I don't really know but that won't help anyway because you are not explaining what kind of result you are actually expecting.

Comment: For example:
Spec table:

Comment: For example:
Spec table:
Dates           Hours
5/5/2016          5
5/5/2016           6
Stats table:
Dates              Cell        Texting
5/5/2016            1              2
5/5/2016             3              4
Query result I want:
5/5/2016          5         1       2
5/5/2016           6         3       4

Comment: Your database as designed does not have the information to do that. Since your only link between the two tables is the date, you are missing the information of which time goes with what stats record. That is why when you actually use a proper ID field to link the two tables and not just the date it works. The ID generates a one to one relationship which is what you want. The date generates a many to many relationship.